# Time Profiler: Optimizing UIImageView alloc/init calls

Tags: iphone, optimization, time, profiler, performance

Time Profiler says that statements like these are slowing my app down. Is there a better way to write this so that my app runs faster?

```
background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myfolder.png"] highlightedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myfolderOFF.png"]];
```

Thanks

Comment: Where's the context for this? Is this in a loop, init, viewDidLoad, etc?

Comment: This code is in a custom init function which loads a custom view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to go ahead and answer my own question with a "you can't."

However if you have an issue like this you COULD try optimize using C

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/04/root-of-all-evil-introduction-to.html

Answer (score 0):

somewhere i've read about "imageNamed:" is evil, but it causes not really performance slowdowns. there were mostly reports off odd bugs and crashes.
Try "imageWithContentsOfFile:"